# change the cost function in K-means clustering python

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

As I know, K-means clustering in python uses Eculdian distance as a cost function. I saw the definition of it in _kmeans.py in python. but I do not know where I can change this cost function. is it possible to change it? I want to use the BD metric (bjontegaard metric) as a cost function? how can I do this? my input data to K-means is an array of RD curves and I want to cluster these RD curves based on BD metric instead of Euclidean distance. could you please help me with this issue? where is the cost function defined in `kmeans` function?

Comment: Would you consider switch to K-Medoids ? It is much easier to change the distance metric for that one